# OpenGL - Multiple Render Target - write only to some targets, discard others

Tags: opengl, glsl

In OpenGL, is it possible to achieve behaviour like this:

```
out float out1
out vec4 out2;

//.....

out1 = /* write some value */
out2 = /* discard */
```

My output targets are R32F and RGBA.

Answer (score 1):

From the official documentation (https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.30.pdf ; page 114-115 of 199) :-

> The discard keyword is only allowed within fragment shaders. It can be
>   used within a fragment shader to abandon the operation on the current
>   fragment.  This keyword causes the fragment to be discarded and no
>   updates to **any** buffers will occur ...

Thus, I believe it is impossible.  (if anyone know the way, please add another answer)
You may workaround with e.g.  :-

```
out1 = /* write some value */
out2 = vec4(0,0,0,0);   // if your blend mode is "add" or "transparent"
```

If your blend mode is currently `oblique`, just change it to `transparent` with `alpha=1`.

### **Discussion**

In the older version of OpenGl, the `ALPHA_TEST` checks only the first target and apply the same result to all the target, so this limitation have existed for a long time.

You can set blend mode for each target *individually* using [glBlendFunci](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBlendFunc.xhtml).

### **Reference**

- specification: https://community.khronos.org/t/use-of-discard-and-return/68293
- ALPHA_TEST : https://community.khronos.org/t/selectively-write-to-one-target-with-multi-render-tagets/67756
- glBlendFunci : https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/662762-glblendfunc-for-multiple-render-targets/